# Data not being passed to parent from child component angular 8

Tags: angular, parent-child

I have a select dropdown which should pass the selected font object back up to the parent. But for some reason and I cannot see why, the key is printing, but the font object is returning undefined. It just doesn't want to bind.

**.html**

```
<app-settings-font-selector (newFont)="getFontValue($event)" [fonts]="fonts"></app-settings-font-selector>
<button class="update" (click)="updateFont('header_font', selectedFont)">Update Font</button>
```

**.child-html**

```
<li>
    <select *ngIf="fonts" [(ngModel)]="selectedFont" (click)="selectFont(selectedFont)">
        <option disabled hidden [value]="selectUndefinedOptionValue">Choose a New Font
        </option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let font of fonts; let i = index;">
            <option [ngValue]="font">{{ font.font_family }}</option>
        </ng-container>
    </select>
</li>
```

**.child-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Fonts } from '../fonts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings-font-selector',
  templateUrl: './settings-font-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings-font-selector.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsFontSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  fonts: Fonts[];

  selectedFont: Fonts;

  @Output()
  private newFont = new EventEmitter<Fonts>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public selectFont() {
    const selectedFont = this.selectedFont
    this.newFont.emit(selectedFont);
  }

}
```

then in my parent, I am doing this:

**parent-component.ts**

```
selectedFont: Fonts;

public getFontValue(selectedFont: Fonts){
  if(selectedFont){
    this.selectedFont = selectedFont;
  }
}

updateFont(key: string){
  console.log(key, this.selectedFont);
}
```

I can't seem to understand why the variable isn't binding. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz of the same? It will be easier for others to check

Comment: Hi, I have a lot of API data coming in so it would take a long time to build out local arrays, so, unfortunately, I cannot. I've tried to put in as much detail as possible, if you need me to show more, just ask and I will edit the question

Comment: You already got good answers, but I would like to comment on the components html. If your including the outer '<li></li>' in the components child-html you wont be able reuse this component so much. It will always need to be inside an '<ul>'. And I dont think it will be usable in forms. Have a look at ControlValueAccessor

Comment: Hi Jens, this component is being reused within the module it has been written in, a settings module. So there won't much need to reuse it across the rest of the application. I see what you are saying, but the use of the child is to share this across a few spots where fonts need to switch, not many different areas of the app. But thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the event emitter name is basically the method you are trying to output from child to parent.

```
<app-settings-font-selector (newFont)="getFontValue($event)" [fonts]="fonts"></app-settings-font-selector>
```

which in your case is newFont.

example: [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-output-example)

Comment: still returns undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I now understand what was going wrong. The click event within the child component doesn't select the font via ngmodel on the first click only on the second click. Which is what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The eventEmitter is the element you must include into your custom html selector `app-settings-font-selector` as the reference. In your case :

```
(newFont)="getFontValue($event)"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this @Gerome - it's worth mentioning here, as you were the first spot it. I have altered the HTML to this, 

<app-settings-font-selector (newFont)="getFontValue($event)" [fonts]="fonts"></app-settings-font-selector> 

as pointed out, but I am still getting undefined. :0

Comment: I'm not fond at all about ngModel and won't be able to help you about that. But you should take a look at this part. I'm not sure you retrieve the option value you select. It would explain why you get undefined as selectFont variable isn't initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In the binding, you must use the name of the @Output parameter. You're using the name of the public method that fires the event.

I the parent HTML the binding should be `newFont` instead of `selectFont`. The following code should work:

**Parent html:**

```
<app-settings-font-selector (newFont)="getFontValue($event)" [fonts]="fonts"></app-settings-font-selector>
<button class="update" (click)="updateFont('header_font', selectedFont)">Update Font</button>
```

**UPDATE:** Also try to move the `console.log` to the `getFontValue` method on parent. Make @output in child public.

Comment: still the same...undefined. :(